# What determines the conjugation of a state in quantum field theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, representation-theory

In basic quantum mechanics, we define the inner product between two states $\phi$ and $\psi$ as $\phi^\dagger \psi$, where $\phi^\dagger$ is the conjugate transpose of the vector $\phi$. However in quantum field theory, we wind up making various modifications that have always seemed ad-hoc to me. For example, in the Dirac equation, we define conjugation as $\bar{\psi} \equiv \psi^\dagger \gamma^0$, where $\gamma^0$ is one of the Dirac gamma matrices. I understand that $\psi^\dagger \psi$ does not give a sensible inner product essentially because the Lorentz group is non-compact,* but I don't know what general principle determines the definition that we actually use.

Things get even weirder for conformal field theories, where we get things like

$$\bar{\phi}(x) = x^{-2\Delta}\phi\left(\frac{x^\mu}{x^2}\right)$$

in radial quantization, where $\Delta$ is the scaling dimension of the field theory (see Eq. 2.14 of [Weizmann Lectures on the Numerical Conformal Bootstrap](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.05147)).

So the question is, what general principle is at work here that determines how we define conjugation and inner products in a general quantum field theory? How can we derive it uniquely, or how much freedom do we have in choosing it?

*Being non-compact prevents us from finding a unitary representation, so we can't have $\Lambda^{-1} = \Lambda^\dagger$, and therefore $\psi^\dagger \psi \rightarrow \psi^\dagger \Lambda ^\dagger \Lambda \psi$ is not Lorentz invariant.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the inner product between states is determined by the structure of the Hilbert space of states $\mathcal{H}_S$ for some state $S$. In your quantum mechanics example, this is the simplest Hilbert space we can have (since it doesn't have any special states that contain modular, conformal, or inversion symmetric states). So, we can just write the inner product as $(A,B) = \int d^Dx\:A(x)B(x)$ where I inserted a fancy $1$ (I think I wrote it correctly for $(A,B)$ since my bra-ket LaTex commands won't work).

But, if we now try to go to a 2D CFT we need a different inner product. The conformal symmetry corresponding to an inversion, $z' = 1/z$ between two Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}_S$ and $\mathcal{H}_{\overline{S}}$ is called the BPZ inner-product. For some operator $\mathcal{O}(z,\overline{z})$ (or state via state-operator correspondence) the correct conjugation is given as
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O}(z',\overline{z}')^T\equiv \frac{(-1)^{h+\tilde{h}}}{z^{2h}\overline{z}^{2\tilde{h}}}\mathcal{O}\left(-\frac{1}{z},-\frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right)
\end{equation}
which is just a conformal transformation composed with an inversion from $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ group. This provides a map from in to out states on a cylinder.(This is actually the conjugation used in string field theory as well).

So, at least that's how I think the inner products of systems are chosen.